# How to mock state data to pass to a function?

Tags: function, testing, jestjs, state, enzyme

I'm trying to test a function that is passed data in order to update the state with using Jest and Enzyme but not sure how to reference the values within the event array? I want to be able to access id, event, and length but it seems that event.id, event.eventname event.length do not work.

```
it("should update state properties using updateProperties()", () => {
  const event = [
    {
      id: 1,
      eventname: "Coachella",
      length: "7 days
    },
  ];
  const wrapper = shallow(<EditEvent event={event} />);
  wrapper.instance().updateProperties(event);
  expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({
      id: 1,
      eventname: "Coachella",
      length: "7 days
  });
```

});

And here is the updateProperties function that I am testing

```
updateProperties(event) {
     this.setState({
       id: event.id
       eventname: event.eventname
       length: event.length
     });
 }
```

I've looked at other stack overflow posts and documentation but haven't found any information that relates to this. Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test, you are passing a wrong argument to your component `updateProperties`: in fact the method expect `event` to be an object but you are passing an array in your test.

```
 const event = [
    {
      id: 1,
      eventname: "Coachella",
      length: "7 days
    },
  ];
```

You only need to pass an object, no `[...]`:

```
const event = { 
  id: 1, 
  eventname: "Coachella", 
  length: "7 days" 
}
```

and your test will pass